# Drupal 8, The file used in the Image field may not be referenced

Tags: 8, files

I am using managed file type to upload image in my custom form (Drupal-8). I am able to retrieve the given image while editing by using the below code

```
$form['image_field'] = array(
   '#type' => 'managed_file',
   '#title' => t('Image'),
   '#default_value' => array($fid),
);
```

While i am trying to save once edit, i am getting the "The file used in the Image field may not be referenced." error.

[image]

Please let me know to over come this error and let me what this error trying to convey.

Answer (score 2):

Check \Drupal\file\Element\ManagedFile for answer, it appears that your file is being saved as permanent, but there is no entry in file_usage table:

```
if ($file = File::load($fid)) {
      if ($file->isPermanent()) {
        $references = static::fileUsage()->listUsage($file);
        if (empty($references)) {
          // We expect the field name placeholder value to be wrapped in t()
          // here, so it won't be escaped again as it's already marked safe.
          $form_state->setError($element, t('The file used in the @name field may not be referenced.', ['@name' => $element['#title']]));
        }
      }
    }
```

If you want to store your files permanently, you need to make sure they've got usage entries, to do so, you can tweak you form submit handler a little bit, here's some quick example:

```
// get file fid wherever it is
$values = $form_state->getValues();
$fid = $values['my_file_field'];

// call file usage service and load file
$file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage');
$file = File::load($fid);

// set file status permanent
if(!$file->isPermanent()){
  $file->setPermanent();
}

// check file usage , if it's empty, add new entry
$usage = $file_usage->listUsage($file);
if(empty($usage)){
  // let's assume it's image
  $file_usage->add($file,'mymodule','image',$fid);
}
$file->save();
```